# How to add a condition in Python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, runtime

In Java, the FOR loop syntax offers a place where we can add a condition. For instance, in the below code the condition is i*j < n

```
for (i=0; i*j < n; i++) 
{ ... }
```

In Python, how can we add such condition in the for loop statement?

```
for i in range(n):
```

I know that we can add an if statement inside the for loop, but I am concerned that it will increase the run time to O(n). Please advice.

Comment: I dont think you will have any diff in O(n) in any case. Instead of `for`, you can use `while` too

Comment: As far as the example goes, you could achieve the same thing with `for i in range(n//j+1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `for` has a complexity of `O(n)`, so a `if` does not change the complexity.

The `for(i=0; i*j < n; i++)` in Java is represented by `while` in Python:

```
i = 0  # initialization
while i * j < n:  # conditions
   do_something
   i += 1  # step
```

Answer (score 1):

When I switched from C to python, this was one of my biggest worries, but it turns out that it is actually a misunderstanding of of syntax. In python, although you can write `for i in range(n)` it is usually a sign that you are doing something else wrong. It is considered better to loop through elements rather than numbers. For a concrete example, in C, you might write

```
for(i=0; i<len(str); i++){
    str[i] blah blah blah
}
```

In python the way you would probably do this is to iterate through the characters directly:

```
for char in str:
    char blah blah blah
```